# Distinct mysql query combine

Tags: mysql

```
select m.*, c.NAME as CORP_NAME 
from MAIL_LOG as m, CORP as c 
where m.SEND_DATE >= '$term_from' and m.SEND_DATE <= '$term_end' ";
```

with

```
Select DISTINCT `TO_NAME_F_KANA` from MAIL_LOG group by m.SEND_DATE;
```

I like to get unique values from the first query with the `TO_NAME_F_KANA` as reference.

Comment: You have no constraint on the join between the MAIL_LOG table and the CORP table in your first query, is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do the trick

```
Select DISTINCT t.`TO_NAME_F_KANA` from 
     (
     select m.*, c.NAME as CORP_NAME 
     from MAIL_LOG as m, CORP as c 
      where 
           m.SEND_DATE >= '$term_from'
                  and
           m.SEND_DATE <= '$term_end'
     ) t
group by t.SEND_DATE;
```

Comment: thank you venc, it works perfectly, can you explain about t, since there is no AS for t, how did it work. Sorry i am newbie on this.

Comment: ok this works great in sql query box in phpmyadmin, but when i added it in php, it gives an error no table found by DB.php (pear library) DB Error: no such field                                                 here is the code                                                   $sql ="Select DISTINCT t.`TO_NAME_F_KANA` from (
                               select m.*, c.NAME,c.ID as CORP_NAME from MAIL_LOG as m, CORP as c where m.SEND_DATE>='$term_from' and m.SEND_DATE<='$term_end')t 
                       group by m.SEND_DATE";                           Any help appreciated.

Comment: t is actually declared as an alias for the subquery just look closely.

I'm not that fluent with PHP so I can't be much of a help but this might have something to do with the use of characters which need to be escaped in PHP string literals. Try also to get rid of the "backticks" which surround TO_NAME_F_KANA they are not really necessary.